# Ruby: Where are remote_address/local_address stored in Ruby Socket object?

Tags: ruby, sockets

The following is a very simple ruby server.

```
require 'socket'

local_socket = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM)
local_addr   = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(4481, '0.0.0.0')
local_socket.bind(local_addr)
local_socket.listen(Socket::SOMAXCONN)

# accept a connection
connection, remote_addr = local_socket.accept
```

After accept a connection, connection is a brand new socket object and has different file descriptor.

```
> connection.instance_variables
[]

> p connection.local_address
Local address: #<Addrinfo: 0.0.0.0:4481 TCP>

> p connection.remote_address
Remote address #<Addrinfo: 59.102.12.1:4481 TCP>
```

My question is:

the instance variable is empty, where are local_address/remote_address stored in this object?

Comment: `local_address` and `remote_address` are instance method of Socket. I failed to find where are they defined.  `connection.method(:local_address).source_location` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

[`#local_address`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/socket/BasicSocket#local_address-instance_method) and [`#remote_address`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/socket/BasicSocket#remote_address-instance_method) are using [`getsockname`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockname) and [`getpeername`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpeername) respectively.

From the [Ruby source code, `ext/socket/basicsocket.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/socket/basicsocket.c):

```
static VALUE
bsock_local_address(VALUE sock)
{
    union_sockaddr buf;
    socklen_t len = (socklen_t)sizeof buf;
    socklen_t len0 = len;
    rb_io_t *fptr;

    GetOpenFile(sock, fptr);
    if (getsockname(fptr->fd, &buf.addr, &len) < 0)
    rb_sys_fail("getsockname(2)");
    if (len0 < len) len = len0;
    return rsock_fd_socket_addrinfo(fptr->fd, &buf.addr, len);
}

static VALUE
bsock_remote_address(VALUE sock)
{
    union_sockaddr buf;
    socklen_t len = (socklen_t)sizeof buf;
    socklen_t len0 = len;
    rb_io_t *fptr;

    GetOpenFile(sock, fptr);
    if (getpeername(fptr->fd, &buf.addr, &len) < 0)
    rb_sys_fail("getpeername(2)");
    if (len0 < len) len = len0;
    return rsock_fd_socket_addrinfo(fptr->fd, &buf.addr, len);
}
```

Comment: So you mean: 

1. the value are stored in system object

2. ruby read those value through C Library. right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Many core objects in Ruby are implemented in C, not Ruby. This is from BasicSocket.